# c++: How to transform a map iterator which point to pair into a "regular" pair pointer

Tags: c++

those are the maps:

```
multimap<SortKey,T> firstMap;
multimap<SearchKey,pair<SortKey,T>*> secondMap;


template <class T,class SortKey, class SearchKey> bool GarageDataBase<T,SortKey,SearchKey>::Add(T data,SortKey key1, SearchKey key2) 
{
 multimap<SortKey,T>::iterator it;
 it=(firstMap.insert(pair<SortKey,T>(key1,data)));
 pair<SortKey,T> *mizi=&*it;

 secondMap.insert(pair<SearchKey,pair<SortKey,T>*>(key2,mizi));
 return true;
}
```

I am trying to insert a pair into the firstMap and get a pointer to this pair and insert it into the "second" field in the secondMap

so that i  could go into my firstMap from the secondmap.

```
pair<SortKey,T> *mizi=&*it;
```

this doesn't compile saying :

```
error C2440: 'initializing' : cannot convert from 'std::pair<_Ty1,_Ty2> *' to 'std::pair<_Ty1,_Ty2> *'
```

any idea whats going on or maybe a better way to make it work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`pair<SortKey,T>` is not the same as `multimap<SortKey,T>::value_type`. The latter is `pair<const SortKey,T>` since the key is not supposed to change. And since `pair<SortKey,T>` and `pair<const SortKey,T>` are not reference-related but two distinct types, the compiler doesn't accept the code. If you account for the `const` key it should work.

Comment: i added the const, still gives the same problem

Comment: @sellibitze This might not be related to the question. Can you please explain why the pair of type `pair<const SortKey, T>` at `*it` will not be deleted when we access outside the member function `GarageDataBase<T,SortKey,SearchKey>::Add` via the global variable, `secondMap`? Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

```
pair<const SortKey,T> *mizi=new pair<const SortKey,T>;
    it=(firstMap.insert(pair<SortKey,T>(key1,data)));
    mizi=&*it;

    secondMap.insert(pair<SearchKey,pair<const SortKey,T>*>(key2,mizi));
    return true;
```

Ok after changing it to const in insert and in the multimap it seems to work

Comment: You have a memory leak here. You allocate a pair using new and never delete it.

Comment: This is just a sample code for testing what i've asked, i'm not gonna use it without deleting all allocations, but thanks

Answer (score 0):

It would be easier to use:

```
multimap<SortKey,T> firstMap;
multimap<SearchKey,firstMap::iterator> secondMap;


template <class T,class SortKey, class SearchKey> 
bool GarageDataBase<T,SortKey,SearchKey>::Add(T data,SortKey key1, SearchKey key2) 
{
   firstMap::iterator it;
             =firstMap.insert(firstMap::value_type(key1,data));
   secondMap.insert(secondMap::value_type(key2,it));
   return true;
}
```

This has several advantages:
 1. don't have to know internal representation of multimap's types
 2. Cannot do something stupid like incrementing the pointers
 but otherwise syntax is the same
SortKey sortkey=secondMap.find(searchkey)->second->first;